# Is that possible to set PresentationsOptions on notifications when my app is on background?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter

I know that we have `willPresent notification` method to be used when my app is in **Foreground**. And I'm looking for a similar way to set the presentation options on my notifications when my app is on **Background**.

Also I know that we have a method for background fetch results, but it does not offer a option to set the presentation option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved to post my on answer in case somebody needs it.
So, instead of send a push notification, I did send a **silent push notification** where `content-available` must be **1**, and `alert` field should not be present on the `aps` payload. In this way, the silent notification will trigger a delegate method `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` where I do create a **local notification**, setting its fields according to my silent notifications `user-info` and schedule it to be displayed or not. This works for background and foreground.

follow this [link](https://github.com/jeremiasdsa/push-notification) for code details:

If the app gets force-quit buy de user, the silent notification will arrive as default behavior. But, no delegate method gets called.